# How to open advertisement when i close the webpage?

Tags: jquery, tabs

I'm working with php e-commerce website. In that site my client want to show his advertisements when user close the browser tab or window. I worked with jquery unload event But its not working.

My code is:

```
$(window).unload(function(event) {
     var url = 'http://www.google.com/';
     window.open(url);
     window.focus();
});
```

Comment: It annoys people - so don't do that

Comment: Most browsers block on-close popups because they've been so severely abused in the past.

Answer (score 4):

Curiously enough, there's a *reason* that code doesn't work. :-) The reason is that it used to work, was abused in exactly this way, and now browser vendors disable opening windows except in direct response to certain user-generated events, like `click` events.

You can't reliably open a new window when the page is unloaded, you'll have to tell your client it's just not an option.